# Floated elements in CSS. Why Can't I acomplish this?

Tags: css, css-float

I'm trying to prevent a floated element from overlapping. In other words, I want my floated element to float all the way to the right if there is room, but if else there is not room, I need to be able to stop the floated element from moving anymore to the left.

This may sound confusing, So I made a small example code:

[My Problem on Jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/nrCpZ/)

I've been at this for hours, I am starting to think this is not possible to do via float, but then again, what I am trying to accomplish I have seen on many website today.

Comment: Looking at your example I still can't tell what the problem is or what is expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can try a couple things.

Try adding:

overflow: hidden; to ad-top-container

also, it looks like it is floating right in your example?